# SwiftUI List looks and behaves differently in Sheet than in NavigationLink

Tags: ios, swift, list, swiftui

I've created a list view with sections for the user to select from *(See LocationPickerModalView.swift)*, this list is available via a NavigationLink and works as expected. However I decided to move this exact view to a Sheet *(See ThrillEditView.swift)*, but this drastically changed how the view looks and worked. *(See Gif below)* Would there be a way to get the same behaviour using a Sheet?

```swift
// ThrillEditView.swift
public struct ThrillEditView: View {
  @State private var isLocationPickerSheetPresented: Bool = false

  public var body: some View {
    form {
      // ...
      NavigationLink("NavigationLink", destination: LocationPickerModalView())
      Button("Sheet (Via Button)") {
        self.isLocationPickerSheetPresented = true
      }
      // ...
    }
    .sheet(isPresented: self.$isLocationPickerSheetPresented, content: {
      LocationPickerModalView()
    })
  }
}
```

```swift
// LocationPickerModalView.swift
public struct LocationPickerModalView: View {
  public var body: some View {
    List {
      Button("1")
      Button("2")
      Section(header: Text("one")) {
        Button("3")
        Button("4")
      }
      Section(header: Text("two")) {
        Button("5")
        Button("6")
      }
    }
  }
}
```

[image: Example of the behaviour]

Comment: They look the same for me (Xcode Version 12.5 (12E262))

Answer (score 1):

The `.sheet` creates new view hierarchy, so you need explicit `NavigationView` in it, like

```
.sheet(isPresented: self.$isLocationPickerSheetPresented, content: {
  NavigationView {
     LocationPickerModalView()
  }
})
```

Comment: This gives the same result, except wrapping it in a NavigationView adds the NavigationBar on top.